# Insert missing data then add data to two previous columns A & B

Tags: excel, vba, date

below is a VBA that when launched I get an error code of 'Run-Time error '13: Type Mismatch'.
It had worked perfectly before for General Format "`dd mmm yyyy hhmm`". After a couple of other VBAs it now in a Custom Format "`dd mmm yyyy hhmm`". The end goal is to have a blank row inserted where a date is skipped over, and have "NO DEPARTURS" placed in the blank row Column A, and for Column B and C have "N/A", and for Column D input the Missing Date in "`dd mmm yyyy 0000`". When debugged the line beginning with d1= cdate... is highlighted.

```
Sub Missing_date()
Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date

r = 1
start:

If Cells(r + 1, "D") = "" Then Exit Sub

d1 = CDate(Split(Cells(r, "D"), " ")(1) & ", " & Split(Cells(r, "D"), " ")(0) & " " & Split(Cells(r, "D"), " ")(2))
d2 = CDate(Split(Cells(r + 1, "D"), " ")(1) & ", " & Split(Cells(r + 1, "D"), " ")(0) & " " & Split(Cells(r + 1, "D"), " ")(2))

If d2 - d1 >= 2 Then
    Rows(r + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
    Cells(r + 1, "D") = Format(d1 + 1, "dd mmm yyyy 0000")
    Cells(r + 1, "A") = "NO DEPARTURES"
    Cells(r + 1, "B") = "N/A"
    Cells(r + 1, "C") = "N/A"
End If

r = r + 1
GoTo start

End Sub
```

Comment: **Editing your question** with an example of your data, in text form that can be copy/pasted into a worksheet; along with screeshots of your desired results (and data if it add clarity), would be of great value in crafting an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to an awful lot of trouble trying to handle dates your own way rather than what Excel would like. I have taken the liberty of presuming that you had no intention of declaring war on Excel. Please try this code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertMissingDates()
    ' 111
    
    Dim NextDate    As Variant
    Dim CellVal     As Variant
    Dim R           As Long                     ' loop counter: Rows
    
    R = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    NextDate = CellDate(Cells(R, "D"))
    If NextDate = vbError Then Exit Sub
    
    ' bottom rows must be inserted before top rows
    For R = R - 1 To 2 Step -1
        CellVal = CellDate(Cells(R, "D"))
        If CellVal = vbError Then Exit For       ' exit if date can't be recognised
        
        Do While Int(CDbl(CellVal)) < Int(CDbl(NextDate - 1))
            Rows(R + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            With Cells(R + 1, "D")
                .Value = Int(CDbl(NextDate - 1))
                .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yyyy hhmm"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            End With
            Cells(R + 1, "A").Value = "NO DEPARTURES"
            Cells(R + 1, "B").Value = "N/A"
            Cells(R + 1, "C").Value = "N/A"
            NextDate = NextDate - 1
        Loop
        NextDate = CellVal
    Next R
End Sub

Private Function CellDate(Cell As Range) As Variant
    ' 111
    ' return vbError if cell's value couldn't be converted to a date
    
    Dim Fun         As Variant              ' function return value
    Dim CellVal     As Variant
    Dim Sp()        As String
    
    CellVal = Cell.Value
    If IsDate(CellVal) Then
        Fun = CDate(CellVal)
    Else
        Sp = Split(CellVal, " ")
            
        If UBound(Sp) = 3 Then
            Sp(3) = Right("0000" & Sp(3), 4)
            Sp(3) = Left(Sp(3), 2) & ":" & Right(Sp(3), 2)
            On Error Resume Next
            Fun = CDate(Join(Sp))
        End If
    End If
    If VarType(Fun) <> vbDate Then
            MsgBox """" & CellVal & """ in row " & Cell.Row & vbCr & _
                   "couldn't be converted to a date.", _
                   vbInformation, "Data format error"
            Fun = vbError
    End If
    CellDate = Fun
End Function
```

The point is that Excel takes a date to be an integer number, like 44135. Tomorrow will be 44136. Therefore each day = 1 and, therefore, each hour = 1/24. 44135.0 is 12AM and 43135.5 denotes 12PM. To display these numbers like 31 Oct 2020 1200 you don't format the number but you format the cell. This is what my code does.

Now you will have cells in your worksheet which have text that looks like a date (your entries) and dates that look like text (entries made by my code). Consider concocting a procedure which looks at the `NumberFormat` of each cell and changes its value to a proper date if it's Text, applying the reqired format at the same time. You can use lines of code from my above procedures to put it together. Then the function `CellDate` would become obsolete because its sole job is to mediate between your text dates and Excel's intentions.

Comment: Thank you so much, However, it is inserting a row for all dates even for the days we have flights. It's much closer than it ever was before. I hope it's just a little tweak needed to fix it. At least we know it works. Also, can we remove the message box since we know it works? the people using this will get confused. I want them to click a button and get their flight schedule. This VBA is about two thirds through 24 VBAs I have. (This is the last one). Thank you.

Comment: Indeed that was imprecise programming and therefore easily correctable. I added `NextDate = CellVal` near the bottom of the procedure. Please amend your code to add this line.

Comment: The MsgBox should not be removed. It points to a "Data format error" as its title states. The solution isn't in shooting the messenger. The `CellDate` function is supposed to be able to read your dates in text format. The MsgBox will only be shown if the attempt fails. Therefore you got two choices. One is to get rid of the text-dates which rends the function obsolete, the other to improve the function to enable it to read those it now seems to fail to read.

Comment: It's fine to change OP's "spaghetti code"-like loop programming; *it might be helpful to insist on fully qualified range references, too :-)

Comment: Good Morning, thank you for the quick response, I did try and place NextDate = CellVal near the bottom of the private function and nothing really happened. I see that it is already in the first portion of the VBA. I did copy and paste again your formula incase I missed something.  Also does it really matter whether I have option explicit? This won't allow me to have it since this is after many other VBAs.  Thanks again. This is so hard been at this thing for nearly a week now.

Comment: I see that you didn't mark the answer as ":Selected". Therefore I think there must still be a bug somewhere that keeps you from enjoying the benefits. Please let me know. what it is. As for `Option Explicit`, MS are mispresenting the option as forcing you to declare variables. Actually, it's a time saver. The more code there is the more time it will save you managing it. But if you think you can save time by not declaring variables - you are right, it's optional.

Comment: I have been trying everything with inserting NextDate=cellVal and unfortunately it is still installing dates even when dates don't need to be installed. I tried to cut and paste your formula again and inserting what you said, Is it possible you can edit your post to exactly the way it should be, this way I'm confident I got the change in the right place? I would want nothing more than be able to mark your answer as selected. Thank you

Comment: @Variatus I have to contradict you if you see `Option Explicit`just as a time saver: I regard `Option Explicit` not only as a necessary contribution to coding (self-)discipline, 
but also as valuable help to understand what I'm doing, 
thus protecting against accidental misspellings and 
possible confusion of any methods and properties or unclear variable scopes.

Comment: Indeed I inserted the extra line in the wrong place. My apologies! Didn't find it until I tried to run the posted code in my own project in which I had the tested code. I moved the line in my answer and feel confident that there are no more discrepancies.

Comment: FANTASTIC! It works beautifully. I was going to use a another VBA code to delete NO DEPARTURES if there was data in the cell immediately below the row. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good morning, I wanted to let you know that your help has been tremendous. Is there anyway that the code could insert the current date at the top row just like for the missing dates further down the rows if the current date (today’s date) is missing? Thank you.

Comment: Most of us, including myself, don't do follow-up questions because they interrupt the Q&A rhythm of this forum. Also, the "you already know my project" presumption is usually wrong at both ends. Follow-up questions need the format of a formal question to be adequately explained and they can't be answered using what I remember from a case I was looking at a few days ago.